# BackboneJS + Require JS + Wookmark.js plugin not working

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I have a Backbone App bound together with RequireJS. Now I want to use the Wookmark plugin https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery but for some reason I cant get it running. So I did the following:

My config.js:

```
require.config({    

   deps: ['main'],

   paths: {
    jquery          : '../lib/jquery-2.1.0.min',
    underscore      : '../lib/lodash-2.4.1',
    backbone        : '../lib/backbone',
    layoutmanager   : '../lib/backbone.layoutmanager',
    handlebars      : '../lib/handlebars/handlebars-v1.3.0',
    imagesLoaded    : '../lib/jquery.imagesloaded',
    wookmark        : '../lib/wookmark.min'
  },

 shim: {
   backbone  : {
    deps   : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
    exports: 'Backbone'
  },
  handlebars: {
    exports: 'Handlebars'
  },
  layoutmanager: ['backbone']
}

});
```

Then in my App.js I have:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'wookmark',
'imagesLoaded',
'layoutmanager',
'handlebars'
],

function ($, _, Backbone, wookmark, imagesLoaded) {
    // some code...

    $(function() {
        var tiles = $('#suptiles'),
                handler = $('li', $tiles),
                options = {
                    autoResize: true,
                    container: $('#supmain'),
                    offset: 10,
                    outerOffset: 15,
                    fillEmptySpace: true,
                    itemWidth: 280,
                    flexibleWidth: 500
                };

        $tiles.imagesLoaded(function() {
            $handler.wookmark(options);
        });
    });     

});
```

Then in my HTML file I did:

```
<div id="supmain">
  <ul id="suptiles">
   <li>some image</li>
   <li>some image</li>
   <li>some image</li>
   <li>some image</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I cna see in my console that both the `wookmark` and `imagesloaded`-plugins are loaded, buut it doesnt get triggered. Does anyone know what might be the issue here?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by simply keeping the `wookmark`-plugin settings in `RequireJS` and  by placing it in an `afterRender` function in the relevant View:

```
afterRender: function(){
    $('#suptiles li').wookmark({
       autoResize: true,
       container: $('#supmain'),
       offset: 10,
       outerOffset: 15,
       fillEmptySpace: true,
       itemWidth: 280,
       flexibleWidth: 500
   });
},
```

Thanks for the many responses though!

Answer (score 1):

You’re calling `$tiles.imagesLoaded` but `$tiles` isn’t defined, nor is the `$handler` you use later. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var tiles = $('#suptiles'),
            handler = $('li'),
            options = {
                autoResize: true,
                container: $('#supmain'),
                offset: 10,
                outerOffset: 15,
                fillEmptySpace: true,
                itemWidth: 280,
                flexibleWidth: 500
            };

    tiles.imagesLoaded(function() {
        handler.wookmark(options);
    });
});
```

The `$` is part of the variable name just like any other allowable character: `$tiles` and `tiles` refer to different variables.

Also, the Wookmark jQuery plugin documentation says this about the `container` option:

```
the width of this element is used to calculate the number of columns, defaults to "window". For example $('myContentGrid'). Container should also have the CSS property "position: relative".
```

[This updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/277TV/4/) seems to be working. I added the necessary CSS and removed the `, tiles` part of the handler declaration (what was that for?).

Comment: Hmm this didnt have any effect at all unfortunately... :-/

Comment: What happens if you manually call `wookmark` in the Javascript console?

Comment: When I console.log(wookmark) nothing happens! So apparently the plugin does not get triggered...!?!?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise. I’m suggesting that you manually execute the code that is supposed to be executed in the script. You can pretty much copy and paste the variable definitions. Then try `handler.wookmark(options)` and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer with a link to a working fiddle and a description of what fixed it.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks alot!!

Comment: Ok, the fiddle itself is working but not when I run it through RequireJS... :-/

Comment: Did you mark the container as `position: relative`? When something doesn’t work as expected, I always break it down into smaller pieces and see whether each works individually in the console. The most important part in this case is that `$('li').wookmark();` should work.

Comment: Yeah, usually I do that too but `RequireJS` and loading external JS-plugins seems to be absolute BS and the result is pure Agony!

Comment: I contacted the `wookmark`-creator and he could confirm, that there is a bug with the require callback when calling imagesLoaded. So thats apparently the reason why it is not working...