# BackboneJS + RequireJS How to add external JS-Plugins

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I want to implement this external JS-plugin, https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery, into my Backbone App. My issue is that I use RequireJS and I really dont know how to get it running. I already asked this before [BackboneJS + Require JS + Wookmark.js plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605607/backbonejs-require-js-wookmark-js-plugin-not-working) but adding it to my App.js doesnt work at all. So does anyone know what might be the issue here?

The wookmark + imagesloaded plugins both appear in my console, so they get loaded. I tried to run it from a View with no success.

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

Since `wookmark` depends on `jquery`, I would recommend adding it to requirejs shim:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'path/to/jquery'
    wookmark: 'path/to/wookmark'
  },

  shim: {
    wookmark: { deps: [ 'jquery' ] }
  }
});
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Do you get any error. Can you see if the $.fn is extended with wookmark?

Comment: @chchrist Didn't really get your question but no, I don't get any errors

Comment: This plugin registers itself to the $.fn of jquery in order for you to use it like this "$().wookmark" https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery/blob/master/jquery.wookmark.js (line 485). So console.log($.fn) and check if it exists.

Comment: console.log($.fn) tells me that `$.fn` exists but the plugin is simply not running. I have other plugins defined in my app.js, they run without problems, just this one doesn't work... :s

Comment: try `console.log($.fn.wookmark)` to check if one exist now

Comment: I placed `console.log($.fn.wookmark)` on 4 different lines in my App.js and I got 2 positive results...

Comment: If `define(['jquery', 'wookmark'], function ($) { console.log($.fn.wookmark) })` returns positive result, the problem is not in requirejs. If so, I would recommend you either edit your previous question removing requirejs-related questions or create new one.

Comment: Could it be possible that I have to attach the plugin inside the relevant Backbone View instead of my App.js?

Comment: It probably would be more approprite in terms of single responsibility, but it really does't matter as long as you have your dependencies set properly.